# Laravel validation rule for email

Tags: php, laravel

I have no idea how to make validation rules for email field not accepting email free account like gmail, yahoo etc.
Can anyone guide me on this topic. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: I hate when I try to use my mail and it is rejected because it is from a free acount.

Comment: Not accepting gmail? You tend to lose 70% of clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a list of email providers into a config file, for example into the `config/email.php`:

```
'banned_email_providers' => '@gmail\.com|@yahoo\.com'
```

Then use the [`regex`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex) validation rule using this list:

```
'email' => ['regex:/^((?!' . config('email.banned_email_providers') . ').)*$/'],
```

Comment: What if your email is gmail.com@nofreeacount.com ? :-D

Comment: @Amarnasan well, a person who created this email deserves to be banned. ) You could probably use a list like `@gmail.com|@yahoo.com`.

Comment: It shows invalid email format for all case. eg. mk@webhopers.in

Comment: @Er.MukeshSharma this is 100% working solution from a real project. Please give some more details. Did you add `webhopers.in` to the banned emails list? Or you've added another validation rule like `email` to this string?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I didn't add webhopers.in  in the list. I am checking for it.

Comment: @Er.MukeshSharma please show the full code you're using right now.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It works fine. Please edit this line by adding square brackets. 'email' => ['regex:/^((?!' . config('email.banned_email_providers') . ').)*$/']

Comment: It also bans mails from yahooacom.net (since the dot in the regexp is matched with any character. But I guess you don't care about sloppy code.

Answer (score 1):

You can store name of mail sites and check email whith its values

```
$free = [
   'google.com',
   'yahoo.com'
];

$mailSite = substr($email, strpos($email, '@') + 1);

if (in_array($mailSite, $free) {
    exit('free email');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this entry to \config\mail.php

```
'banned_servers' => ['yahoo.com', 'gmail.com']
```

Then

```
    $rules = [
        'email' => array('regex:/@(?!' . implode('|', array_map(function ($item){return str_replace('.', '\.', $item);}, config('mail.banned_servers'))) . ')/')
    ];

    $messages = ['email.regex' => 'Email accounts from '. implode(', ', config('mail.banned_servers')) . ' are not allowed'];

    $this->validate(Request::instance(), $rules, $messages);
```